# Need to redirect when permission issue happened on CiviCRM Page

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, permissions

I have enabled and configured access for Contribution financial type. When an anonymous user open the a contribute page, it returns the error.

[image: Error Page]

I need to redirect to login page in this case. I don't want to show error page to the user.

Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by specifying your custom Fatal Error Handler at `Administer -> System Settings -> Debugging and Error Handling`.

- Enter the name of the function eg `myCustomErrorHandler` for `Fatal Error Handler` input field.
- Define this function in one of the [extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/) `.php` file. The param should hold the message of the error and if it matches the permission text msg, you can use redirect function to navigate to the login page. Eg.

  ```
  function myCustomErrorHandler($params) {
    if ($params['message'] == 'error message') {
      CRM_Utils_System::redirect($urlyouwant);
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
  ```
- Note the return statement in this function. `FALSE` is required to call the default error handler in case your function wasn't able to do the needful.
- `return TRUE;` will not call the default Error handler in CiviCRM.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jitendra's answer, check Drupal's CiviCRM permissions. Look for "CiviContribute: make online contributions" and make sure all roles, such as anonymous, are checked..

[image]